# Does crontab file automatically bash a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, wget

I have a crontab job setup. In the crontab file, I have a path to a text file. My text file has a wget command (which in turn, executes a PHP file). If the crontab file just has the path  to the text file, will it automatically bash (execute) that text file? Or do I need to prefix the path to the text file with bash?

Comment: You can try it out by copying the "command" portion of the line into a shell, and pressing return. If it says "Permission denied" or another error, then you'll need to check things as suggested by other answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the file is executable (check if it has x in `ls -l`, if not, then use `chmod` to set the executable bit) and the first line contains `#!/bin/bash` then it will be interpreted in bash.

The other option is, as you suggest, to pass it as an argument to bash:

```
/bin/bash /path/to/your/file.sh
```

Comment: So, my script should do the following:
1stline: #!/bin/bash
2ndline: wget insertweburl here

Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. And use `chmod +x <file>` to set the executable bit. Also, you should probably use the full path to wget, since cronjobs usually run a "bare" environment where `$PATH` might not include the directory where the wget binary resides.